# INNER JOIN too slow. how can it bee quicker

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My code

```
SELECT * FROM andmed3 INNER JOIN test ON andmed3.isik like concat('%', test.isik, '%')
```

In andmed3 i have 130 000 rows and on test i have 10 000 rows, and it wont run.
When i limit it to 0,500 then it will query about 2-3 minutes.

How can it be better?

andmed3 table

```
id   name   number   isik   link   stat   else
----------------------------------------------- 
1   john    15     1233213  none    11     5
                   8455666
                   7884555
```

test table

```
id    isik
-----------
45    8455666
```

So i need all the rows from the andmed3 where is number what occures in test

Comment: Your join is based on `non-sargable` condition `LIKE '%...%'`. To speed it up you should rethink join (adding artificial keys maybe) or use FULL-TEXT index.

Comment: It seems due to bad schema desing....may you show sample output of both tables as well schema...

Comment: whats the relation between andmed3  and test

Comment: But i need the % like % as the test tabel contains number  what is allso one number from the andmed3 tabel

Comment: `SELECT * FROM andmed3 INNER JOIN test ON andmed3.isik = test.isik like concat('%', test.isik, '%')`, along with relation.

Comment: try to add index "isik", but don't think it will very much helpful.

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu Adding a index ill not help because indexes cannot be used here while you need to evaluate a expression. Also that expression is not a good one to be put inside a index

Comment: Can you add some sample data to the question to show the need for the wildcard? At the moment, it looks as though you ought to be able to use an equijoin, which should be *much* faster.

Comment: Couple of cases you can improve the query. #1 is select couple of specific collumn  except *.  #2 is at on try to use id relations and #3 is use andmed3.isik like cases at where clause. I hope it would be faster.

Comment: Mark, the table thing is sample data.

In the "isik" collumn i have 1-10 rows of numbers divided by \n line break.
And on the other tabled test i have only the isik numbers(one) and i need the row from the andmed3 table where the test table number exist

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the engine ill need to avalute the **LIKE** expression for each pair of rows in the join (130.000 X 10.000).
Also indexes are useless in this scenario because the expression need to be evaluated in order to accomplish the join (and you cannot put that expression INSIDE a index)

Maybe it's your architecture/schema the problem. When no one antecipated the need to join two tables based in a string expression.

Possible solution:

(It's a wild guess)

Hard to tell for sure from your example but if andmed3.isik contains all possible values to be used in the join you can try to put that in another table like it:

```
Andmed3Id    isik
--------- -------
        1 1233213 
        1 8455666
        1 7884555
```

Of course to populate this table you ill need a strategy, possbile ones are: in the insert/update, in a batch in some late hour.

If this suits you just need to add one more join in your query.